# Remove bibliography title and pagebreak from \bibliography

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

I would like to remove the title 'Bibliography' and the pagebreak which is put automatically using \bibliography{myPublications}.
So far, I have found that with \renewcommand{\bibname}{}
 you can remove the title, and \renewcommand{\chapter}{} removes the pagebreak, but leaves an asterisk in the pdf. \renewcommand{\chapter*}{} gives the error: \chapter *undefined.
Any workaround?

```
\section*{Publications}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{}

\nocite{myPaper}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{publications}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this *very particular* case, you can try

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@gobbletwo}
\makeatother
```

which makes `\chapter` gobble two tokens following it, meaning the `*` and the title argument.